# Why does Axios send my POST request with Content-Type application/x-www-form-urlencoded when using a string as the request body?

Tags: javascript, spring, typescript, axios, http-headers

I found this interesting behavior with axios while making POST requests. I am sending URLs that the user types in to my Spring RestController which accepts the request body as a String. It looks like this:

```java
@PostMapping("user/{userId}/link")
public ResponseEntity<UserLinkDTO> addUserLink(
    @PathVariable(value = "userId") Integer userId, @RequestBody String url) {
    ...
}
```

On the front end, my axios request looks like this:

```js
const saveUserLink = async (userId: number, url: string): Promise<UserLinkDTO> => {
  return axiosInstance.post(`user/${userId}/link`, url))
  .then(r => r.data)
);
```

When I send some arbitrary URLs (with `=` in them) like these:

`https://www.google.com/search?client=firefox`

`https://www.yahoo.com/somePage?key=value&hello=world`

the Spring POST method receives the `url` exactly as it was sent.

However, when I send some URLs like this (without any `=` in them):

`https://www.google.com`

`https://www.yahoo.com/somePage`

my Spring POST method receives the `url` with `=` appended to them! So the links are received as:

`https://www.google.com=`

`https://www.yahoo.com/somePage=`

I noticed the requests are being sent with `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` in my Network tab. However, based on [axios docs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios#using-applicationx-www-form-urlencoded-format), all requests should be serialized to JSON which would imply being sent with `Content-Type: application/json`. All the other requests I'm using are sent with `Content-Type: application/json`. It's only this one that gets converted to `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded`.

I edited my axios post request to include some custom headers so I could change the `Content-Type` back to `application/json`:

```js
const saveUserLink = async (userId: number, url: string): Promise<UserLinkDTO> => {
  return axiosInstance.post(`user/${userId}/link`, url, {
    headers: {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    }
  })
  .then(r => r.data)
);
```

My Spring POST method is now able to receive the URLs above exactly as provided, regardless of if they have `=` in them or not. There is no longer an extra `=` appended to the links without any `=`.

Why is it that axios seems to change the `Content-Type` from `application/json` to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` when providing a string as the request body?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the default content-type in axios is 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

```js
//https://github.com/axios/axios/blob/master/lib/defaults.js
var DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE = {
  'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
};

//...

utils.forEach(['post', 'put', 'patch'], function forEachMethodWithData(method) {
  defaults.headers[method] = utils.merge(DEFAULT_CONTENT_TYPE);
});
```

while when request's data is an Object, axios sets contentType to 'application/json':

```
    if (utils.isObject(data)) {
      setContentTypeIfUnset(headers, 'application/json;charset=utf-8');
      return JSON.stringify(data);
    }
```